# iTerm auto-capitalising everything

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, iterm2, autocorrect

I recently bought a Mac Mini in the office. I had installed Mountain Lion Developer about a month before the official release. Everything worked perfectly except for the fact that in iTerm it'd auto-capatalise my lines.

It's really frustrating. A lot of commands are case-sensitive obviously.

It doesn't seem to happen anywhere else. I've upgraded to the release edition of Mountain Lion now it's out.

Help would be really appreciated.